# Unable to use setOpacity() to make both x and y axes invisible in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I am using JavaFX to plot a bubble chart and I want the background to be completely free of any of the lines including the lines for the x and y axes.
I have successfully removed the horizontal and vertical grid lines and the ticks.

This is what my graph currently looks like

[image: snapshot]

I am trying to remove the faint grey line which is the x axis which can be seen at the bottom.
To remove the yAxis I set `yAxis.setOpacity(0)` which successfully makes the yAxis invisible but when I do the same for the x Axis I am left with a line. Can I not perform `setOpacity()` function for both the axes simultaneously? If not how do I remove the line?

Here are the list of statements I have tried so far:-

```
    blc.getXAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    blc.getYAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    blc.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
    blc.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    blc.setLegendVisible(false);
    blc.getYAxis().setOpacity(0);
    blc.getXAxis().setOpacity(0);
    xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
    yAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
```

where blc is the object for the Bubble Chart class

Comment: Hi Anwesha, welcome to SO. Can you please provide some code samples of what you have tried so far? This will help people understand your problem easily. Take a look at our how to ask guide. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please focus some code.